# SQL Select 2 colum with same name from 2 table

Tags: sql

I have made this query:

```
Select type from client, store etc...
```

I have the "type" field in both tables, as I can only choose one of the customer table?

Comment: Question is not clear at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the table name in front

```
Select client.type 
from client
join store on ...
```

Comment: Where did customer alias name come from ?

Comment: OP mentions a table named `customer` that he joins - probably a typo and he ment `client`. Updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: Don;t encourage teh use of implicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select client.type, store.type,  
from client
join store on store.id = client.storeID
```

It is critical to always alias all columns in a query. That is simply good practice. It makes maintenance much easier.

Further, NEVER use implicit joins. THey are a SQL antipattern, they create problems with accidental cross joins, you can't tell if you really need a cross join or if it was an accident and they are harder to maintain especially if you end up with people mixing implicit inner joins and explicit outer joins which may even end up giving you incorrect results.

Answer (score -1):

Use the table name. If you want type to come from table store, use:

```
Select store.type from client, store etc...
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want both, you will have to alias names:

```
select client.type as clienttype, store.type as storetype from client, store etc...
```